# jQuery snippets for PhpStorm

Tags: jquery, phpstorm, code-snippets

Recently I switched to PhpStorm (and its awesome).

Now, I'm looking for jQuery snippets like ones in Sublime.

Yes, I know how to write them but I was wondering is there some kind of package or already defined solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check https://github.com/WilliamStam/WebIDE-Live-Templates, https://github.com/fprochazka/phpstorm-livetemplates. I believe that you can find even more templates on the web

Comment: Thank you. 
Seems useful :)